# Creating thousands of records in Rails

Tags: ruby, database, optimization, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Let me set the stage:  My application deals with gift cards.  When we create cards they have to have a unique string that the user can use to redeem it with.  So when someone orders our gift cards, like a retailer, we need to make a lot of new card objects and store them in the DB.

With that in mind, I'm trying to see how quickly I can have my application generate 100,000 Cards.  Database expert, I am not, so I need someone to explain this little phenomena:  When I create 1000 Cards, it takes 5 seconds.  When I create 100,000 cards it should take 500 seconds right?

Now I know what you're wanting to see, the card creation method I'm using, because the first assumption would be that it's getting slower because it's checking the uniqueness of a bunch of cards, more as it goes along.  But I can show you my rake task

```
desc "Creates cards for a retailer"
task :order_cards, [:number_of_cards, :value, :retailer_name] => :environment do |t, args|
  t = Time.now
  puts "Searching for retailer"
  @retailer = Retailer.find_by_name(args[:retailer_name])
  puts "Retailer found"
  puts "Generating codes"
  value = args[:value].to_i
  number_of_cards = args[:number_of_cards].to_i
  codes = []
  top_off_codes(codes, number_of_cards)
  while codes != codes.uniq
    codes.uniq!
    top_off_codes(codes, number_of_cards)
  end
  stored_codes = Card.all.collect do |c|
    c.code
  end
  while codes != (codes - stored_codes)
    codes -= stored_codes
    top_off_codes(codes, number_of_cards)
  end
  puts "Codes are unique and generated"
  puts "Creating bundle"
  @bundle = @retailer.bundles.create!(:value => value)
  puts "Bundle created"
  puts "Creating cards"
  @bundle.transaction do
    codes.each do |code|
      @bundle.cards.create!(:code => code)
    end
  end
  puts "Cards generated in #{Time.now - t}s"
end

def top_off_codes(codes, intended_number)
  (intended_number - codes.size).times do
    codes << ReadableRandom.get(CODE_LENGTH)
  end
end
```

I'm using a gem called readable_random for the unique code.  So if you read through all of that code, you'll see that it does all of it's uniqueness testing before it ever starts creating cards.  It also writes status updates to the screen while it's running, and it always sits for a while at creating. Meanwhile it flies through the uniqueness tests.  So my question to the stackoverflow community is:  Why is my database slowing down as I add more cards?  Why is this not a linear function in regards to time per card?  I'm sure the answer is simple and I'm just a moron who knows nothing about data storage.  And if anyone has any suggestions, how would you optimize this method, and how fast do you think you could get it to create 100,000 cards?

(When I plotted out my times on a graph and did a quick curve fit to get my line formula, I calculated how long it would take to create 100,000 cards with my current code and it says 5.5 hours.  That maybe completely wrong, I'm not sure.  But if it stays on the line I curve fitted, it would be right around there.)

Comment: Have you tried it without transactions?

Comment: Before I knew that transactions existed, I was just creating them without that transaction block.  The transactions sped up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but a couple of suggestions on how to make the insert faster:

- Use Ruby's `Hash` to eliminate duplicates - using your card codes as hash keys, adding them to a hash until your hash grows to the desired size. You can also use class [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html) instead (but I doubt it's any faster than Hash).
- Use **bulk insert** into the database, instead of series of INSERT queries. Most DBMS's offer the possibility: create text file with new records, and tell database to import it. Here are links for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) and [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/sql-copy.html).

Comment: I was trying to implement your hash suggestion, but I ran into some trouble.  I understood the uniqueness testing when I'm generating the codes.  But how will I test for uniqueness against the cards that are already in the DB?  Also, I was trying to implement your import idea, and I'm using a gem I found called activerecord-import.  So I'll give it a test here in a minute and I'll see if that helps.

Comment: I didn't end up using the hash, for the reason I mentioned in my last comment, but I did some runs with the activerecord-import, and along with some newly added indexes, I got my time for 100,000 down from over a day to 5.5 minutes!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yup, uniqueness can be tricky to ensure completely. Another thing you can try instead of your `readable_random` are UUIDs - they tend to be unique, as they include (but don't disclose) the creation timestamp, along with random part. I think that using UUIDs you can treat collisions as exceptions, not as a rule.

Comment: Oh, here's another idea: you can skip Ruby/Rails completely for performing this task, using stored procedures in PostgreSQL. Make retailer_id and desired_number_of_cards input parameters, and create your input records in a loop in a stored proc.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty good idea! I'm pretty clueless when it comes to databases, but I'll definitely look into it.  We upgraded our database on Heroku to their Ronin package, and that sped up card creation for 100,000 to 3.5 minutes.  But I'll definitely look into both UUIDs and Postgres procs.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts would be around transactions - if you have 100,000 pending changes waiting to be committed in the transaction that would slow things down a little, but any decent DB should be able to handle that.

What DB are you using?

What indexes are in place?

Any DB optimisations, eg clustered tables/indexes.

Not sure of the Ruby transaction support - is the @bundle.transaction line something from ActiveModel or another library you are using?

Comment: I'm using postgreSQL, which is hosted on Heroku.  I don't have any indexes in place, besides the default, but I'll definitely give it a try and post back.